# PHP MYSQL data count retrieve from mysql gone wrong

Tags: php, mysql, select, count

I'm new to php and MySQL.  I have a table which I build with this SQL

```
CREATE TABLE classs
(sid INT(11) NOT NULL,
cid INT(11) NOT NULL,
lid INT(11) NOT NULL,
 date DATE NOT NULL,
UNIQUE (sid, cid,lid,date));
```

My database input is

```
sid || cid|| lid date (ALL DATE IS DIFFERENT with in case of same ID)
==================================
2001      ||  1001   || 8
2001      ||  1001   || 8
2002      ||  1001   || 8
2003      ||  1001   || 8 
2003      ||  1001   || 8
==================================
```

Here, I need to build a code using php to display the result like this

```
2001          2
2002          1
2003          2
```

i use this code on my view.php

```
<?php
require_once('core/init.php');

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","studentattendancesystem");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql="select *,count(sid) from classs group by sid";
$result = $con->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0)
{
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
  {
    $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $sid = $row["sid"];
    echo $sid, " ", $rowcount," ","<br>";    
  } 
}
else
{
  echo 'Failed';
}
```

but my output is

```
2001         3 //should be 2
2002         3 //should be 1
2003         3 //should be 2
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `GROUP BY` what? You're missing something there. When learning MySQL you should have [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/) open at all times in a browser tab and any time you're curious about how a statement works, check out the docs for that.

Comment: group by student id, sir. so, if the student id occurs twice, it will count as 2. but my code give me wrong answer :'(

Comment: @xNour That's not what it says in your code. Also there's no need for formality, especially not the awkwardly gender-specific variety.

Comment: *"but my output is (code)"* - So, what is the expected output?

Comment: it is group by sid (student id), sorry i posted wrong code, but mine have group by sid, still run incorrectly. please help :'(

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We were all beginners once. The only stupid question is the unasked one. The purpose here is to help you, and to build a vast database of questions and answers. Therefore, your words of supplication are not necessary. I will edit them out.

Comment: the output should be 2,1,2 as i have 2 (2001) 1 (2002) 2 (2003) but my result is 3,3,3

Comment: even if $sql="select count* from classs where sid='2001' it will return 1 instead of 2

Comment: sorry sir i put studentID only for this question so helpers will understand it is student id, not sid. but in my real database and code, i use sid,cid,lid. sorry for being confusing

Comment: Although I'm Canadian and say "sorry" an awful lot, there's no need to repeatedly say that. Cheer up a little, eh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing I think we are all missing is that he is setting `$rowcount =mysqli_num_rows($result)`.

So of course he is getting three, `$row` count needs to be set to: `$rowcount = $row['count']` as in Ollie's example.

Comment: can u please be more specific? i dont understand

Comment: $sql="select *,count(sid) count from classs group by sid";
$result = $con->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0)
{
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
  {
    //$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $rowcount = $row['sid'];
    $sid = $row["sid"];
    echo $sid, " ", $rowcount," ","<br>";    
  } 
} // this code gives me weird output. :'(

Comment: in your query, set it up like Ollie's (count(*) count (this sets it to an alias of count), then in your php code put `$rowcount = $row['count'];`

Comment: Glad to help, I know I use this site alot when I get stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is incorrect

```
select *,count(sid) from classs group by sid
```

Should be

```
SELECT studentID,COUNT(*) FROM classs GROUP BY studentID
```

**[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/37968/2)**

Comment: Gives correct output to me (just like you said you wanted), see the fiddle.

Comment: the correct out put should be 2001 2 || 2002 1 || 2003 2

Comment: So do you not see that output in the fiddle?

Comment: I noticed in your fiddle that you do not use the unique command, why is that and is that what xNour is doing wrong?

Comment: There is no need for UNIQUE when you are grouping the results on same field.

Comment: i need to avoid duplicate if i send same data means same (sid,cid,date,lid). this is why i make it unique :'(

Answer (score 0):

Pro tip: Don't use `SELECT *` in a query in a program unless you know *exactly* why you are doing so. It is likely to be wasteful and incorrect, especially in a query containing `GROUP BY`.  Also, avoiding `SELECT *` will make you get your column names right in your query.

You are trying to summarize your raw data by student id..

This query will do that for you.

```
SELECT studentID, COUNT(*) count
  FROM class
 GROUP BY studentID
```

I have put it into a sqlfiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5c6d1/1/0

I *think* your tables are more complex than what you have showed us. In that case, you may be mistaken about the example data.

At any rate, most developers troubleshoot queries like this using a straightforward SQL client like phpMyAdmin or HeidiSQL or something. Then they embed them into their php.

Comment: This works. However, I have a question about `COUNT(*) count`, why the word "count" after `COUNT(*)`? *Curious.*

Comment: still wrong :'( i already do what all of you teach me. but still i am wrong. i do this on my mysql "select sid,count(sid) from classs group by sid" and i got my answers. but when i do in php it goes all wrong and weird. pleaseeeeee help me :'(

Comment: @xNour if it works in your SQL client, then copy and past it to your PHP code and check the output in your console.

Comment: i does it. but it still give me wrong answers. i tried make new table and try to retrieve the data based on same concept. however, even though there is 3 same id, it will count as 1, and all other different id altogether.

Comment: @Fred-ii-   `COUNT(*) count` causes the resultset column name to be `count` rather than `COUNT(*)`. It's just a column alias. No big deal.

Comment: @OllieJones Thanks. Yeah, I figured it out after lol *cheers*